# Weekly aggregation of dataframe by category

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, aggregate

I have data grouped by Date and Category.

```
Date        Category  Revenue
2000-01-01  TV        1050.5
2000-01-01  DVD       500.2
2000-01-02  TV        750.4
2000-01-02  DVD       750.3
...         ...       ...
```

I have to aggregate this data weekly. For each category I need weekly revenue. It's gonna be time series, so, if I understand correctly, groups have to be a features. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require(tidyverse)
df <- read.table(text='Date        Category  Revenue
2000-01-02  TV        1050.5
                 2000-01-02  DVD       500.2
                 2000-01-03  TV        750.4
                 2000-01-03  DVD       750.3', header = T)
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(week = lubridate::floor_date(as.Date(Date),'week')) %>% 
  group_by(week, Category) %>% 
  summarise(Revenue = sum(Revenue))
```